# Is accepting connections from a cloned TcpListener thread safe / portable in Rust?

Tags: rust, tcp

In Rust, I am experimenting with a server design such that threads independently listen for tcp connections on the same port, and whoever accepts the connection, gets to process and handle it. Here's a basic, example idea of what I mean:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    let listener_clone = listener.try_clone().unwrap();
    let original_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        match listener_clone.accept() {
            Ok((_socket, addr)) => println!("thread got new client: {:?}", addr),
            Err(e) => println!("thread couldn't get client: {:?}", e)
        }
    });
    match listener.accept() {
        Ok((_socket, addr)) => println!("main got new client: {:?}", addr),
        Err(e) => println!("main couldn't get client: {:?}", e)
    }

    original_thread.join().expect("The thread being joined has panicked");
}
```

This results in, if two tcp requests are sent via curl,

```
main got new client: 127.0.0.1:57370
thread got new client: 127.0.0.1:57372
```

My question is calling `accept()` on a `TcpListener` cloned via `try_clone()` from another `TcpListner` thread safe, or otherwise atomic ? Also, is it portable between platforms, with no undefined behavior? My example program, and ones similar to it, do work with basic testing, but the Rust docs do not guarantee such behavior officially.

Comment: yes but who receive who is unspecified.

Comment: better question s why do you think it's not thread safe ? everything in rust is thread safe if you don't use unsafe

Comment: also note that I never saw a real word application that clone a listener TCP socket

Comment: In this case, the implementations for the `TcpListener` in rust would be different for each OS, and I thought perhaps some of those OS specific socket functions may be not thread safe or undefined behavior. I will change the wording to portable.

Comment: I expect that why it's call `try_clone` thus returning an error if the underline OS can't support this

Comment: From [`TcpListener::try_clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.try_clone): "The returned TcpListener is a reference to the same socket that this object references. Both handles can be used to accept incoming connections and options set on one listener will affect the other". I've skimmed the docs and it looks like all targets that support `TcpListener` will forward the clone to the OS.