Thread spawning does not run thread-spawned function in Rust
The general idea of the server is to spawn certain amount of threads with task of handling streams.
That's the minimal issue-causing server program:
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};

use std::thread;

use std::env::{args, Args};

fn handle client(mut Stream: TcpStream) {}

fn handle_streams(listener: &TcpListener) {
   for stream in listener.incoming() {
      match stream {
         Ok(stream) => {
            handle_client(stream);
         }

         Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("connecting fail, cause: {}", e);
         }
      }
   }
}

fn main() -> () {
    let arguments: Args = args();
    let arguments_string_vector: Vec<String> =  arguments.collect();
    let listener_ip_address: &String = arguments_string_vector.get(1).unwrap();
    let listener_port: &String = arguments_string_vector.get(2).unwrap();
    let listener_address = format!("{}:{}", listener_ip_address, listener_port);
    let listener_bind_error_message = format!("bind fail on {}", listener_address);
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(listener_address.clone())
        .expect(&listener_bind_error_message);
    println!("listening on {}", listener_address);

    let threads_demand_quantity_string: &String = arguments_string_vector.get(5).unwrap();
    let threads_demand_quantity: u32 = threads_demand_quantity_string.parse().expect("threads demand not defined");
    for _i in 1..=threads_demand_quantity {
        let listener_clone = listener.try_clone().unwrap();
        thread::spawn( move || {
            handle_streams(&listener_clone);
        });
    }
}

The issue-causing part is:
for _i in 1..=threads_demand_quantity {
   let listener_clone = listener.try_clone().unwrap();
   thread::spawn( move || {
      handle_streams(&listener_clone);
   });
}

The issue is, that nothing inside thread-spawned function seems to be running or done (I checked it simply by putting marker println! inside thread-spawned function and to the handle_streams). The server finishes it's work causing no errors. How to fix thread-spawned function to make it run?
As an evidence, that it's the individual-case issue, I've checked similair code:
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;


fn main() -> () {
   for _i in 1..=10 {
       thread::spawn( move ||
           {
               println!("thread");
               thread::sleep(Duration::new(3, 0))
           }
       );
   }
}

and:
use std::thread;

fn secondary(arg: &str) {println!("{}",arg)}

fn main() -> () {
   for _i in 1..=10 {
       thread::spawn( move ||
           {
               println!("thread {}", _i);
               secondary(&"arg")
           }
       );
   }
}


Won't you have multiple listeners on the same port, which will fail for all but the first to bind to that port?

The usual way to do a multi-thread server is to have a single thread listening for incoming connections, which then passes each accepted connection to another thread for processing.

Checked something about it. The question may be answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759515/is-accepting-connections-from-a-cloned-tcplistener-thread-safe-portable-in-rus in comments.             TO https://stackoverflow.com/users/299924/trojanfoe

Your main thread is not waiting for anything, so it returns from main(), and the process just exits. The idiomatic way to wait for workers is to collect the thread handles in a Vec, and then wait for them one by one. (The threads will of course still run in parallel, so this sequential wait is not sequential.) See this question for an example. Alternatively, you can use std::thread::scope(), which will wait for all spawned threads automatically, to enforce lifetime safety.

You aren't waiting for your threads so main() spawns then but then immediately exits the program.
